# How to install correctly this PiWallet Script in Ubuntu?

Tags: json-rpc, php, error, daemon, connection

Good evening everyone.
  I'm trying to set up the piWallet wallet (https://github.com/johnathanmartin/piWallet) on Linux.

I was able to successfully install the "Bitcoind Server" (which works very well when I type in a Terminal the commands "**bitcoind -daemon**" and then "bitcoin-cli getinfo", I get ***the Info of Blocks, Balance, etc. ..***), PHP5 (then the Script is based on PHP5), PHPMyAdmin, Apache2 and MySQL on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.
But the concern I encounter is that the file "jsonRPCClient.php" fails to connect the client and displays the following error:

```
Warning: fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:8332/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in /var/www/html/piwallet/jsonRPCClient.php on line 133

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://greg:pass123@127.0.0.1:8332' in /var/www/html/piwallet/jsonRPCClient.php:141 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/piwallet/classes/Client.php(17): jsonRPCClient->__call('getbalance', Array) #1 /var/www/html/piwallet/classes/Client.php(17): jsonRPCClient->getbalance('zelles(chegadmi...', 6) #2 /var/www/html/piwallet/index.php(22): Client->getBalance('chegadmin') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/piwallet/jsonRPCClient.php on line 141
```

I do everything but Zero; no solution; I even searched the internet but no satisfactory answer. The bug to check if PiWallet really connects to the Daemon Server (Bitcoind), I run "greg:pass123@127.0.0.1:8332" in a Browser, and I get the following error saying that we did not Need authentication to connect to 127.0.0.1:8332.

Help me really because I need it.